# LibVLCSharp: cannot view the RTSP

Tags: c#, vlc, libvlc, libvlcsharp

I am trying to start a capture of the webcam, transcode it and output it to `RTSP` but I cannot view the stream when I view: rtsp://127.0.0.1:53211

I get a log in my VLC player saying:

```
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'rtsp://127.0.0.1:53211'. Check the log for Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'rtsp://127.0.0.1:53211'. Check the log for details.
```

I don't see any logs in C# side and I see my webcam lights up so I assume it's accessing the webcam.

```
using System;
using LibVLCSharp.Shared;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Core.Initialize();

            using var libVlc = new LibVLC();
            using var mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(libVlc);

            mediaPlayer.EndReached += (_, x) =>
            {
                Environment.Exit(1);
            };

            var media = new Media(libVlc, "v4l2:///dev/video0", FromType.FromLocation);
            media.AddOption(":v4l2-standard=ALL :live-caching=300");
            media.AddOption(":chroma=mp2v --v4l2-width 1280 --v4l2-height 720");
            media.AddOption(":sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,acodec=mpga,fps=30}:rtp{mux=ts,sdp=rtsp://:53211}");
            media.AddOption(":sout-keep");

            mediaPlayer.Play(media);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two errors:

1. This option is malformed and causes a silent error

```cs
media.AddOption(":v4l2-standard=ALL :live-caching=300");
```

2. RTSP URL is malformed and needs path at the end

```cs
media.AddOption(":sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,acodec=mpga,fps=30}:rtp{mux=ts,sdp=rtsp://:53211}");
```

Solution in C#:

```
var media = new Media(libVlc, "v4l2:///dev/video0", FromType.FromLocation);
media.AddOption(":chroma=mp2v --v4l2-width 1280 --v4l2-height 720");
media.AddOption($"::sout='#transcode{{vcodec=h264,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}}:rtp{{sdp=rtsp://{GetLocalIPAddress()}:53211/live.sdp}}'");
media.AddOption(":no-sout-all");
media.AddOption(":sout-keep");
```

Command line:

```
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma=mp2v --v4l2-width 1280 --v4l2-height 720 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://192.168.0.107:53211/live.sdp,proto=tcp}' :no-sout-all :sout-keep
```

Comment: no spaces in option strings

Comment: no `--` in media option strings, only in libvlc option strings. Media options need `:`